# Unable to launch lidar during boot

Tags: ros, rplidar, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have an [rplidar](https://github.com/robopeak/rplidar_ros) and i want to launch it during the booting. I followed a rosanswer [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/245089/systemd-roslaunch/) and was able to launch roscore during the bootup. But I am unable to launch rplidar.

```
/etc/systemd/system/
*********************rosCore.service************
[Unit]
Description=start roscore
After=network.target
Restart=on-abort

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/rosCoreService.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

**********************************************
/usr/local/bin/
*******************rosCoreService.sh **********
#!/usr/bin/env bash

bash -c "source /home/bc/.bashrc && roslaunch rplidar view_rplidar.launch"

****************************************************
```

I tried ./rosCoreService.sh directly and its working fine.  In order to have port permissions
I added KERNEL="ttyUSB0", GROUP:"bc", MODE = "0666" in /etc/udev/rules.d/50-usb-serial.rules

Since i need some port permission is
"After=network.target" is correct ?  or any suggestions ?  I replaced "roslaunch rplidar view_rplidar.launch" with "roscore" and roscore is launching while bootup.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288623/unable-to-launch-lidar-during-boot/) by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2018-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Posted it here in case if some one needs it in the future.

```
/etc/systemd/system/
******* rosCore.service *************
Unit]
Description=start roscore
Restart=on-abort

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/rosCoreService.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
**********************************************
/usr/local/bin/
*******************rosCoreService.sh **********
#!/bin/bash
source /home/bc/.bashrc
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source /home/bc/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
roslaunch rplidar_ros rplidar.launch

***************************************************
```

Observe that i have changed #!/usr/bin/env bash to  #!/bin/bash, not sure why but i just followed few online discussions.

---

Originally posted by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) with karma: 241 on 2018-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0